# multilevel dict access and understanding key value relation

Tags: tcl

Input dictionary is defined like in example below.

```
dict set a b C {d E f G h {{I} {J} {K}}}  
dict set a b L {d M f N h {{O} {P} {Q}}}
```

I want to access values I,J,K for C and O,P,Q for L
I tried dict keys $a and I can just access value b, do not know how to traverse further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict get`.  The first argument is the variable value `$a`.  The remaining arguments are the named nested keys of `$a`.

```
tclsh> dict get $a b C h
{I} {J} {K}
tclsh> dict get $a b L h
{O} {P} {Q}
```